# Encryption in Android using RSA algorithm with given modulus and exponent

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I have previously used a RSACryptoServiceProvider in C# to encrypt some data, and now I have to replicate this encryption in an Android program. I want my Android program to generate the same result as I got in my C# program.

**Public Key:**

```
<RSAKeyValue>
    <Modulus>zz4qdc39y1BHyJgVXUkINJSbsUd1ZJPISyE9nNGjqgR+ZO1a4cE3ViVCSZCw+6dBdVMFNjzZPBxl0mT57GIq7rcuoT0scesZgxOftbMasPbxp0BGrh3HTpbBMJdCopgcYV98CZERakb8Pgbb0ne/DiW9Aq0kfTBE02/iEHRNuqMNfo1GFo55m0OKbxVoM6UBb8AITQ6lbdvfCgeIvMzRlVrHCwxUNrrX5cS6gurEfJ8Da+prKQmwWpFCkwDkPWje2W+bTSPUc9l6Ads0UimYE5sGs4Zsfz6Eocz4rJjR+qCiB8qt6HtdyjKo0auqYzyXIjdRv2950flc9tOh5bRlQQ==
    </Modulus>
    <Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

**Java Encryption Program:**

```
byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(Modoutput.getBytes("UTF-8"),
        Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(Expoutput.getBytes("UTF-8"),
        Base64.DEFAULT);
BigInteger e = new BigInteger(1, exponentBytes);
BigInteger m = new BigInteger(1, modulusBytes);
RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey pubKeyn = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);

Log.i("Publickey", pubKeyn.toString());
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKeyn);
byte[] encryptedByteData = cipher.doFinal(byteData);
String outputEncrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedByteData,
        Base64.NO_WRAP);

Log.i("Encrypteddata", outputEncrypted);
```

I tried the above code but it gives an entirely different output from C#. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

---

***Edit***: As requested, here is the C# code for which I am trying to replicate the encrypted output in Java:

```
public static string EncryptText(string text, int keySize,
        string publicKeyXml) {
    var encrypted = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), keySize,
            publicKeyXml);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
}

public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int keySize, string publicKeyXml) {
    if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Data are empty", "data");
    int maxLength = GetMaxDataLength(keySize);
    if (data.Length > maxLength)
        throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(
                "Maximum data length is {0}", maxLength), "data");
    if (!IsKeySizeValid(keySize))
        throw new ArgumentException("Key size is not valid", "keySize");
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicKeyXml))
        throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicKeyXml");

    using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize)) {
        provider.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
        return provider.Encrypt(data, _optimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding);
    }
}
```

Comment: We probably can't answer the question until you post your C# code too. Also, please explain what data type `Modoutput` is. That whole section looks questionable - why are you base64 decoding bytes, rather than working with strings?

Comment: @DuncanJones:Modoutput is of String DataType;it is the same modulus which i have mentioned in the public key and i required byte format of Modoutput.please tell if i have to format my code.

Comment: @DuncanJones:  C# CODE: public static string EncryptText(string text, int keySize, string publicKeyXml)
        {
            var encrypted = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), keySize, publicKeyXml);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

Comment: @DuncanJones: kindly check C# CODE

Answer (score 4):

Encryption by definition tries to hide all information about the plain text. This includes information about identical plain text. To do this it uses some kind of random within the various padding modes (e.g. PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible padding or OAEP padding for [RSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)). So speaking from a cryptographic standpoint, the implementation is *broken* if you ever get an identical result.

The method to check if the ciphertext is correct is by decrypting it using the private key. If that results in the plaintext you started with then your implementation is correct.

[EDIT] Note that you are using OAEP encryption in the C# code, while Java uses the PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible scheme by default. You should use `"RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"` or `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"`. If it is not available add the Bouncy Castle provider.